# Using Turtle graphic's onscreenclick() event but need a return value from the function binded to it

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm just some code that binds a function to my mouse click on the turtle graphics screen as such:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()

def token_move(x,y):
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    position = [turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()]
    return position

token = turtle.Turtle()
wn.onscreenclick(token_move)
```

Now my problem is that I want the coordinates that the turtle is at after the mouse click so i can use it for the rest of my program, but because it is binded to the onscreenclick() event I can't return any value from token_move. I've tried changing the last line to:

```
position = wn.onscreenclick(token_move)
```

But had no luck either. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `token_move` function could append the (x,y) coordinates to a global list, and the other parts of your program could access the coordinates from that list. Maybe you should explain a bit more about what you want the rest of your program to do. In the mean time, it may be helpful to read a tutorial on event-driven programming with `turtle`, eg [Event-Driven Programming](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/events.html#event-driven-programming) from _How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3_.

Comment: @2Ring, thank you for your reply. I am trying to create a connect 4 game using python and turtle graphics. I'd like to get the user to click on which column (0-6) on the game board to play their game piece in. My approach to this is to use the onscreenclick() method to use the x/y coordinates from the mouse click to determine what column the game piece should fall into. For example, if 0<x<10 and 0<y<10, then return column 0.

Comment: Ok. So you just need to put the code that draws the player's game piece in a function, and call that function inside `token_move`. BTW, there's no need to do `position = [turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor()]` since you already have the x & y coordinates in the args that `token_move` gets called with.